# Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit - no improve button!

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I wanted to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605120/html-css-how-to-create-horizontal-lines-inline-with-text), which at the time had a pending edit.

Clicking the edit link under the question gave me a dialog with this at the top:

[image: Dialog header without the promised button]

However, there is nowhere visible to choose to improve the suggested edit - the options are "Approve and reopen", "Approve and leave closed", and "Reject".

Clicking the "Edit question" button in the section

[image: Closed notofication section]

takes me to that question in the suggested edits queue, where there is no text suggesting that the edit can be improved.

Should the first part of the first dialog above be re-worded?

Comment: In my opinion a "improve and reopen" and "improve and leave closed" options should be added, rather than fixing the text. A few times I found a good edit, reopenable question, but a few improvements could help the edit. I needed to approve and reopen, open the question separately and edit again

Comment: This should probably be a question on MSE as requested by the team on the [announcement question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/786798) - looks like a good case for a feature request (not sure if it was requested before)

Comment: @OlegValter The error is not after transitioning to the review queue, where there is no mention of improving the edit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is directly related to this change. See bullet 2 under *Changes to the Reopen votes queues* in the link Oleg provided

Comment: @Tomerikoo There isn't a problem with the wording in the review queue - the dialog with the wording problem is reached by clicking the edit link under the question. I've edited my question to clarify which "edit" I mean.

Comment: Yes, but if you would encounter that edit in the queue, the same will help. Bottom line this problem is related to the recent queue changes. If we wouldn't get the new "approve and reopen" option, there wouldn't be a problem to begin with... Anyway, I support this bug report and as I said in a previous comment - I personally think the solution is actually adding more options and not changing the text

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ah, I see what you mean now.